# When fitting with TPOT CV, is the fitted_pipeline_ retrained on the whole dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tpot

I am using a LeaveOutGroupOut CV strategy with TPOTRegressor

```
from tpot import TPOTRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut

tpot = TPOTRegressor(
    config_dict=regressor_config_dict,
    generations=100,
    population_size=100,
    cv=LeaveOneGroupOut(),
    verbosity=2,
    n_jobs=1)

tpot.fit(XX, yy, groups=groups)
```

After optimization the best scoring trained pipeline is stored in `tpot.fitted_pipeline_` and `tpot.fitted_pipeline_.predict(X)` is available.

my question is: what will the fitted pipeline have been trained on? e.g.

- does tpot refit the optimised pipeline using the entire dataset before storing it in `tpot.fitted_pipeline_`?
- or will this represent a trained pipeline from the best scoring split during

Additionally, is there a way to access the complete set of trained models corresponding to the set of splits for the winning/optimized pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPOT will fit the final 'best' pipeline on the full training set: [code](https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/blob/9c712821c400d3b67f4045b451c687d7fb783a5d/tpot/base.py#L744:L748)

It's therefore recommended that your testing data never be passed to the TPOT fit function if you plan to directly interact with the 'best' pipeline via the TPOT object.

If that is an issue for you, you can retrain the pipeline directly via the `tpot.fitted_pipeline_` attribute, which is simply a sklearn Pipeline object. Alternatively, you can use the `export` function to export the 'best' pipeline to its corresponding Python code and interact with the pipeline outside of TPOT.

> Additionally, is there a way to access the complete set of trained models corresponding to the set of splits for the winning/optimized pipeline?

No. TPOT uses sklearn's `cross_val_score` when evaluating pipelines, so it throws out the set of trained pipelines from the CV process. However, you can access the scoring results of every pipeline that TPOT evaluated via the `tpot.evaluated_individuals_` attribute.